# Yuk- Chan Docker image in GitLab

Tags: docker, http, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I was using the Docker image of Yuki-Chan in GitLab but i'm having some troubles. 
I get recurrent this error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='https', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: //target (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f10e72d7190>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

do you any idea about the cause?

Thank you very much!